# SonarQube in Azure DevOps wtih Microsoft Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

As our SonarQube instance was not accessible over internet, I am getting the below error in "Prepare analysis on SonarQube" task during the analysis of a java project.

*[SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ENOTFOUND","errno":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"ABC.XYZ.com","host":"ABC.XYZ.com","port":443}*

Some links suggests that by adding proxy variable will solve this issue. But don't know how to do it. Some links suggests to install agent service (from Deployment Pool section) will solve this issue. In that case we need to do it for multiple organization.

So anyone please let me know what will be the proper solution for this issue.

Comment: Hi @Kattesang, how are things going? Does it work using the self-hosted agents on the host of your SonarQube server? If you have any updates, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @Bright Ran, As of now the requirement was on hold. So not able to comment on your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this problem when using **SonarQube** on **Azure DevOps Services** (**VSTS**), installing self-hosted agents generally is a better way to solve the problem.

To install self-hosted agents on multiple organizations, you can try to set up a shell script that executing the installation command lines in a loop to install a self-hosted agent for each organization.

Comment: Whether running deployment pool script on SonarQube server will solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @Kattesang, deployment pool in an organization can be shared between the projects only in this organization, and can't be shared to other organizations. So the deployment agents (actually are self-hosted agents) in the deployment pool can't be shared between organizations. You still need to set up a deployment pool and install deployment agent for each organization.

Comment: Yes Bright Ran. I agree that deployment pool script also needs to be run in every organization. But my question is after running the script whether azure devops able to connect sonarqube. I mean the above error will be resolved.

Comment: @Kattesang, Sure, it is the very best way if you are able to directly install the self-hosted agents on the host of your SonarQube server.